# An app compiled with Android Studio runs factor 2 slower than built with Eclipse ADT

Tags: java, android, eclipse, performance, android-studio

I created a benchmark app that calculates a mandelbrot fractal using a selectable number of threads and in single/dual precision. Now when google/android force me to migrate from Eclipse to AS I imported the code without change and the resulting app takes a factor of 2 .. 2.5!! more time to calculate the same image! If someone want's to try:
AS Project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/52aou8v60thekxg/AACqfowW4hHvF1-1g0CbJzEJa?dl=0
Eclipse Project:  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g41jehf87dcpe2r/AACZykrSNq3dy4JocNfKmbLNa?dl=0
Both folders contain also the apks.

How can different android 'compilers' create differently performing code? Is there a possibility to select optimization options? I was not able to create an unsigned "release" apk, only "debug" apks. Would it make a difference? In Eclipse every debugable build was this factor 2 faster.